# SCons: mark target as built

Tags: python, scons

I have a build script which I can’t control that builds everything (shell command that generates lot’s of files), but most of the time it’s sufficient to build just a few files, instead of running the whole script.

My SConstruct file looks like this:

```
cmd1 = env.Command(<main executable file path>, [], <build everything shell command>)

cmd2 = env.Command(<target file path 1>, <source file path 1>, <build file 1>)
cmd3 = env.Command(<target file path 2>, <source file path 2>, <build file 2>)
```

What I want is to mark cmd2 and cmd2 command targets as built, without actually building it if cmd1 target was built, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the command1 builds target 1 and target2?

that's really back to front if so.

the idea of a build system is it builds from the bottom up. It builds each piece you need, then puts all the pieces together to get a bigger piece, and so on.

It doesn't consists of one huge script to build everything and lots of little scripts to part build some of the things that the big script builds anyway.

You should be considering some structure like:

```
cmd2 = env.Command(<target file path 1>, <source file path 1>, <build command 1>)
cmd3 = env.Command(<target file path 2>, <source file path 2>, <build command 2>)
cmd1 = env.Command(<main executable file path>, [cmd2, cmd3], <link everything command>)
```

Comment: Yes, command1 builds target1 and target2. I do understand that my case is not conventional. Here is some background, I do have a Python program that I package with py2app into stand-alone Mac application. I do not want to run it all the time during development (there is an a lisa mode for that, but it's still slow). I don't want to rewrite py2app using SCons, it's easier to run py2app if building from scratch, and then only copy/build changed files, without running py2app.

Comment: So make that a separate target that shares some of the sources with your other targets if necessary.

Comment: If I understand you correctly it will not solve the problem, if py2app is run (and build everything), the other targets (that copy / build individual files) will still run and I don't want them to run in this case.

Comment: I'm not familiar with py2app but if as a result of doing that build, you've done the builds for various other targets, then you have your build structure upside down and in fact your py2app build is dependant on various other builds. Without seeing your entire build system, I can't be certain, but that's what it looks like from where I'm sitting.

"build everything" is generally the wrong thing to do, and you should be building lots of individual things then merging them as the last step